# Modify inter-SE advertising algorithms to show different questions (or switch them out for new ones please)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, advertising

**UPDATE: Old adverts still in place - I implore SE to change them. Upvote this question to implore also. Somebody will come to our rescue... eventually... I'm sure.**

---

I appreciate and even enjoy the fact that popular questions are advertised between SE sites.  The one qualm I have is the same old top-voted questions get continuous attention in the advert box and become boring fast. Likely they're continuously contributed to and bumped.

For example, the [MMO question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-is-so-hard-to-develop-a-mmo) from GameDev has been consistently advertised to me on StackOverflow over the past **many weeks maybe months**. I tire of seeing it and other reoccurring questions especially considering there are many new and interesting questions since then.

**Suggestion/Solution**

I'm requesting the SE inter-advertising algorithms be revisited and modified to stop the same old "interesting" questions from being re-displayed continuously and indefinitely. Possibly a sliding window of time should be applied to capture newer questions that are more recently popular.  Otherwise a static queue of question adverts might be cycled using more recent content.

If I want to see the all-time highest voted or popular questions I can easily do that  by visiting the [Questions] nav button of any particular SE site.

I don't have to mention  Fallout Vegas Ammo packs and Karma, or How to Make [Bacon Powder](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/846/how-can-i-make-bacon-powder) because they're burned into our brains from months of impressions.

Comment: I hope this doesn't seem too irrelevant, but I gave +1 largely because I never knew the word "quip" could be used that way. :)

Comment: "quip" changed to "qualm" There's not even that many Qs :)

Comment: @John K: haha, but I hope you didn't think I was being ironic; the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quip) does list "quibble" as one of the meanings of "quip", and this fits the context well enough... The more Qs, the merrier.

Comment: @John K & @Mitch Schwartz This is quite the quirky quomment queue!

Comment: I'd go with quibble, but if we carry on like this, the question is going to get closed as 'belongs on English' :)

Comment: Curiously, the attention the advertised questions get is not entirely positive, one of my advertised questions had to be locked due to useless/spammy answers.

Comment: Would that be a querulous, quarrelsome or quasi-quavering quibble? Quite a quandry! Quick, query this quantity of qualified quantum quartermasters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.  We now display hot questions from the site with a custom background image & font for each site.  Previously it was, as others have noted, a static image that Jin designed for each site.

Comment: the new ads look great! I was antsy to get rid of the static image ads as well, and now we can show a greater variety of interesting questions on the network..

Answer (score 3):

I think that would be useful, yes. I know I'd have a much greater chance of clicking across to a site if I saw a little bit more of what was there.

I think I've assumed that maybe the ad was static (as in, it's not actually pulling from the site dynamically, but was designed just like any other 'banner ad' and put in the rotation). If some dynamic ads showing various questions were there instead, I think I'd be more likely to check out the other sites. I know the MMO question in particular doesn't do anything to make me want to check out the site, for example.

Comment: If they are in a static queue I'd recommend they be replaced with a general advert for the theme of  the site. Then at least I'd be brought to the main and current page of questions without having to go through a really old one.

Answer (score 1):

The ads are static images, Jin showed the gaming ads in chat before they went live. So I think at the moment all changes would have to be done by hand.

For the gaming ads there is the added problem that the design of the ads is Fallout-specific, so it would have to be changed to show something other than Fallout question. I think that is not a problem for most of the other sites.

I also think that the questions should be switched at least once in a while.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if somebody might even code something use the SE API to dynamically grab recent questions adverts - of course some level of moderation might need to be applied if that were the case.